# Comparison between multiprocessing and parallel processing

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cpu, computer-science, terminology

Can someone tell me the exact difference between multiprocessing and parallel processing? I am little bit confused. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

**Multi Processing**

> Multiprocessing is the use of two or more central processing units
>   (CPUs) within a single computer system. The term also refers to the
>   ability of a system to support more than one processor and/or the
>   ability to allocate tasks between them.

**Parallel Processing**

> In computers, parallel processing is the processing of program
>   instructions by dividing them among multiple processors with the
>   objective of running a program in less time. In the earliest
>   computers, only one program ran at a time.

Answer (score 5):

Multiprocessing: Running more than one process on a single processor

parallel processing: running a process on more than one processor.

Answer (score 4):

**Multiprocessing**
A processing technique in which multiple processors or multiple processing cores in a single computer each work on a different job.

**Parallel processing**
A processing technique in which multiple processors or multiple processing cores in a single computer work together to complete one job more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is a misunderstanding(at least I had) that all these concepts use the terms CPU, Core, and processor interchangeably. However, they do not mean the same. 1 CPU back in time(before the 90s or so) used to have only 1 Core, but now 1 CPU has many cores like dual-core, quad, 8, 16, etc. So we should not say based on CPU, instead either core or CPU core(because the core is part of a CPU, 1 CPU core means one of the cores inside the CPU).

Now,

**Multi-processing**: Multiple programs/processes running on as many CPU/Core/processors. Multi-processing is only possible when there is more than 1 CPU core/Core/processor.

**Parallel processing**: One program is divided into loosely coupled independent tasks, each running on a different CPU core/core/processor.

PS: You might argue that multiple programs running on multiple CPU cores are also independent, just like in Parallel processing.

And yes, that is True!

However, the catch here is there is no context switching/time-slicing in Parallelism, but actual parallel work of independent tasks(no blocking I/O, etc, or dependency/interrelated task)

In the case of multi-processing, the distributed tasks can or cannot be interrelated, so there can be some blocking calls on the processor/core and thread being in a tasks/programs blocked/waiting state.

You can say Parallelism computing is a specialised case of Multi-processing, where tasks are not at all interrelated (having no dependency on each other).

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing operating systems enable several programs to run concurrently. UNIX is one of the most widely used multiprocessing systems.Multiprocessing means the use of two or more Central Processing Units (CPU) at the same time. Most of new computers have dual-core processors, or feature two or more processors, therefore they are called multiprocessor computers.

Parallel Processing:The simultaneous use of more than one CPU to execute a program. Ideally, parallel processing makes a program run faster because there are more engines (CPUs) running it. Most computers have just one CPU, but some models have several. There are even computers with thousands of CPUs. With single-CPU computers, it is possible to perform parallel processing by connecting the computers in a network.

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing is doing a work with the use of many processors or cores.
Parallel processing is dividing one or more work into small parts and give every part a chance to process.

Answer (score 0):

MULTIPROCESSING:simply means using two or more processors within a computer or having two or more cores within a single processor to execute more that more process at simultaneously.

PARALLEL PROCESSING:is the execution of one job by dividing it across different computer/processors.