# what is difference between multiprocessing and parallel processing?

Tags: parallel-processing, operating-system, multiprocessing

This question might be a duplicate question.

Like I understand during Parallel processing, CPUs/cores work on a single task(program or process) to make total execution time shorter, and during multiprocessing CPUs/cores, work on a completely different task (tasks don't have anything in common), this is done to make total execution time shorter. Am I right?
I also have another question: if multiprocessing or parallel processing makes the program faster why we don't use it every time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparison between multiprocessing and parallel processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841095/comparison-between-multiprocessing-and-parallel-processing)

Answer (score 2):

There are many resources for this already. For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18841095/13020139) and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-multiprocessing-and-parallel-processing).

Multiprocessing is used all the time on modern computers that have 2+ cpus and more than one schedule-able process. Parallel processing requires extensive programming effort and there is a limit to parallel execution speedup one can achieve on a program (look up Amdahl's law).

Comment: can i use multiprocessing on 1 cpu which has multiple cores?

Comment: Great question. That gets into physical cpu vs logical cpu cores topic. Many resources on that you can look up as well. Using the term "multiprocessing" is mostly a semantic thing in this context. What ultimately matters is if your program/computer actually achieves a speedup. The answer is it depends (probably) (on programming language, on program type, scheduling specifics, etc.). As for the semantics, theoretically, I would say yes multiprocessing could include any computer with 2+ cpus (whether physical or logical cores).

Comment: I have one more question: if multiprocessing only gives speed up, then I shouldn't have access to it, because it should be the default for every program and programmers shouldn't write it.

Comment: If you're asking how to take advantage of multiprocessing, here's an example. You write a python program. Instead of making it run parallel threads, which from personal experience and mentioned elsewhere online Python can't take advantage of on logical cores, you make those threads into processes. Since your Python program now spawns off processes, those processes can be scheduled to logical cores and you can see the speedup you wanted.

Comment: Multiprocessing as a general term is the ability to run multiple processes at the same time by different cpus. Unless you're trying to speed up a specific program you've written (which except for my python example above, you are probably better off trying multithreading), modern OSes already handle scheduling multiple processes on different CPUs so you don't have to worry about it when opening different programs, for example.

Comment: There are a couple other reasons of when to explicitly write your program using multiprocessing vs. multithreading discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19928448/13020139).